# Google Books Display Thumbnail in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, oop, google-books

Using Codeigniter 3, I would like to display a HTML table consisting of some book details, namely *Item ID, Item Image* and *Item Title*. I would like to populate the Item Image via Google Books.

So far my code works, in the sense that I can retrieve all the data from the MySQL database and display it in a simple HTML table. However I'm not sure how to populate the image field in the HTML table with the corresponding image from Google Books.

I am retrieving the ISBN from my database, can I use this to lookup the Google Books URL?

I tried to create a `foreach` as you will see but it doesn't work so I have commented it out. The error message I receive in the `foreach` is;

> Message: Undefined index: items on line 23

My current code is below;

**Model**

```
class Items_model extends CI_Model {
    public function itemList() {
        $query = $this->db->get('item', 10);
        return $query->result_array();
    }  
}
```

**Controller**

```
class Items extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('items_model');
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['items'] = $this->items_model->itemList();    
        //foreach ($data['items'] as $row)
        //{
        //  $page = //file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:".$row['item_isbn']); 
        //  $bookData = json_decode($page, true);
        //  $data['BookImage'] = '<img src="'.$bookData['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail'].'" alt="Cover">'; <-- line 23
        //}
        $this->load->view('item_view', $data);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
        <td><strong>ISBN</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Image</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
    </tr>

<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item['item_id']; ?></td>         
            <td><?php echo $item['item_isbn'] ?></td>    
            <td><?php // what goes here? ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $item['item_title']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Googlebooks API to get the id of your book.

First you have to make a request in this way:

```
foreach ($items as $item):
$data = @file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn+".$yourISBN."');
$data = json_decode($data);
$data = $data->items[0]->id;
// Next you have to insert $data(the item_id) inside of one of the 
followings links:
 //  "smallThumbnail":  "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
 //  "thumbnail": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
 //  "small": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=2&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
 //  "medium": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=3&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
 // "large": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=4&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
 //  "extraLarge": "https://books.google.com/books?id=zyTCAlFPjgYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=6&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"

//Example: 
$thumbnail = "https://books.google.com/books?id=".$data."&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api";
    endforeach;
```

And then you've got your thumbnail.

Note that your id must have this format "zyTCAlFPjgYC".
Have a look at the [doc](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/getting_started)

Comment: Thanks @totor59 but I now receive the following error `Undefined index: id.` A `var_dump($data)` returns `NULL`

Comment: See my last edit I gave you the wrong index for the id